# SQL - Explode the dates between the ranges as new records

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I want to perform a explode kind of task in mysql, where I need to create new records per day from the start and end dates.

Current data looks like this:

```
Person, Start Date, End Date, Score
a     , 12/05/2017, 14/05/2017, 0.8
a     , 15/05/2017, 17/07/2017, 0.3
b     , 12/05/2017, 14/05/2017, 0.5
b     , 15/05/2017, 17/07/2017, 0.2
```

Now, I need to re create the data as

```
Person, Date,  Score
a     , 12/05/2017, 0.8
a     , 13/05/2017, 0.8
a     , 14/05/2017, 0.8
a     , 15/05/2017, 0.3
a     , 16/05/2017, 0.3
a     , 17/05/2017, 0.3
b     , 12/05/2017, 0.5
b     , 13/05/2017, 0.5
b     , 14/05/2017, 0.5
b     , 15/05/2017, 0.2
b     , 16/05/2017, 0.2
b     , 17/05/2017, 0.2
```

Since, I am joining this tables with other tables on date & person column, this operation is needed. How I can I do this in MySQL?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? When it comes do date/time many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant. (E.g. those two, in different ways.)

Comment: what db version u are using ?

Comment: `CROSS JOIN` to a `TALLY TABLE` Please provide the DBMS that  you are using

Comment: I am using Mysql

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query to get your result -

```
create table PersonTable (
 Person varchar(10), StartDate   date   , EndDate date, Score float
)
go


insert into PersonTable   
select 'a'     , '2017-05-12', '2017-05-14', 0.8
union all select 'a'     , '2017-05-15', '2017-07-17', 0.3
union all select 'b'     , '2017-05-12', '2017-05-14', 0.5
union all select 'b'     , '2017-05-15', '2017-07-17', 0.2

create table #DateList (Date_Time date)

declare @MinDt Date , @MaxDt Date

select @MinDt=  Min(StartDate) , @MaxDt = Max(EndDate) from  PersonTable
while (@MinDt < = @MaxDt)
begin
 insert into #DateList
 select @MinDt 
 select  @MinDt =  dateadd(day,1, @MinDt) 
end  

select t1.Person , t2.Date_Time , t1.Score from PersonTable t1
join #DateList t2 on 
t1.StartDate <= t2.Date_Time
and t1.EndDate >=t2.Date_Time
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is work for above question in SQL SERVER

```
create table  TempTable      -------Creating table 
(
Person varchar(20),
[Date] date ,
Score float
)


Declare @person varchar(20),@StartDate date,@Enddate date,@Score float,@temp int = 1,@count int ;                 -----------Local variable declaring

select @count = count(*) from <YourTableName>      ------Row count

while ( @count > 0)
begin

with CTE_Select
as
(
select row_number() over (order by Person) id,  * from [dbo].[difference_table]
)
select @person = Person,@StartDate = [Start_date],@Enddate = End_date,@Score = Score from CTE_Select
where id = @temp               -------------Taking first Row

Declare @diff int = datediff(dd,@StartDate,@Enddate)
while (@diff > 0 )
begin
insert into temptable (Person,[Date],Score)
select @person,@StartDate,@Score 
set @StartDate = DATEADD(dd,1,@StartDate)
Set @diff = @diff - 1
end
set @temp = @temp + 1                         ---------------selecting next row
set @count = @count - 1                       ---------------decreasing row count
end ;
select * from TempTable;                     ------------Select modified table
```